# Eclipse: Web Services Option is missing

Tags: eclipse

This not a programming question but Most of the programmers using Eclipse should have the answer I am lokking for.

I am running eclipse Indigo (v 3.7). But I dont find the option to create a web services client.

My googling has so far suggested that I should do following:

File -> New Project-> Other
Under "select Wizard" pop up window, Select "Web Services" option.

So, in my case, I do not see "Web Services" at all.

This version was running on windows, So I install Eclipse on my ubuntu box and still I do not see the "Web Services" option there.

I think I am missing something.

Could you help me figure this out. I started learning Eclipse quite recently.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what "kind of" Eclipse do you use. I guess it has to be this: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/
or you you will have to install the appropriate plugins for being able to develop web related projects

Comment: Ok. Thanks.

On windows, I downloaded th eclipse which is availalbel on [http://www.eclipse.org/]. There is a download button on hte right handside and I downloaded it.

On Ubuntu, I used the command "aptitude install eclipse" and it install eclipse.

So, as you suggested, I need to instal the plugin. Could you provideme name of hte plug-in and I will try installing the same.

Thanks again.

Comment: use update site (help/install new software - select all available sites). I guess 'Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools' should do the trick

Comment: however if you have just installed Eclipse, I guess you could also download the version I suggested and use that from now on.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that what i had download was "Eclipse Classic". Now i downloaded "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" and I see "Web Services" out of the box. thanks.

Comment: It's not Web Developer Tools as mentioned above.  You can do a help->install new software and install WST components.  You don't need them all.  You can unchek Group option and select the ones that look right (core/common/etc) and leave the ones that you don't need

Answer (score 2):

First, never install Eclipse from a Linux package manager like apt; always download directly from www.eclipse.org
Second, to get the web service features, you probably want to download the **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers** package. That package includes the Web Tools Project plugins that give Eclipse its web services features (among other things).

Comment: Thanks. I realized that what i had download was "Eclipse Classic". Now i downloaded "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" and I see "Web Services" out of the box. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You either:

1. **Download the plug-in for Java EE Developers in your current Eclipse** (assuming you have a valid Eclipse IDE downloaded from a valid/existing publisher, see https://www.eclipse.org/downloads for the most recent version(s) or https://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/ for older versions of Eclipse).

The Java EE Developers plug-in can then be downloaded. Check out the YouTube https://youtu.be/oBhAzf9ac9A
After downloading, you should now see the Web Services option.

**OR**

2. Install a new Eclipse IDE that supports Web Service development named: **Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers** from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/.